# Don't wait for dialog to be dismissed but still store the returned answer? (Applescript)

Tags: macos, dialog, applescript

Using `ignoring application responses` I am able to execute code while a dialog is still open like so:

```
ignoring application responses
    (display dialog "Type some text:" default answer ¬
        "" buttons {"Okay"} default button 1)
end ignoring
display dialog "boo"
```

(In this example the code to display the message "boo" doesn't wait for the first dialog to be answered before executing.)

So obviously when I try to store the result of my first dialog like so:

```
set myText to ""
ignoring application responses
    set myText to (display dialog "Type some text:" default answer ¬
        "" buttons {"Okay"} default button 1)
end ignoring
return myText
```

`return myText` gives the error: `"myText is not defined"`

***Is there a way to not wait for the dialog to be answered and still get the result?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course that's not possible. The main reason is that AppleScript runs in a single synchronous thread.

As the name implies `ignoring application responses` doesn't wait for the response to the sent Apple Event `sysodlog` (display dialog). The variable `myText` is unset and the next line is executed immediately.

See also the error message `No result was returned from some part of this expression.` when you add the code to get the returned text directly

```
set myText to text returned of (display dialog …
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there an alternative option to using `ignoring application responses` that might work or is it just outright impossible?

Comment: consider again `single synchronous thread` ? AppleScript cannot perform asynchronous code in the same handler, it's impossible

Comment: Ah, well. I just wanted to double check I'd understood correctly. Thanks.

Comment: You could execute another script (without waiting for the script to complete) that generates the dialog, grabs & processes the response. If you were particularly ambitious, you could even save what you want to get back in a file that the parent script occasionally checks to retrieve the result.

Comment: hepcat72's suggestion sounds like it will work. You should try it. Or, use python instead, a **real** programming language. Python can run as many threads as your memory can handle and you can run AppleScripts from within python and retrieve the result.